# How to find exact time difference in minutes between two date columns?

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table named Temp_cperf with created_date and updated_date columns. I want to get the time difference in minutes from these two dates.

Created_date: `16-SEP-23 15:08:14`
Updated_date: `16-SEP-23 15:08:35`

I have written query like this.

```
select round((Updated_date - Created_date)*24*60,2) Time_DIFF
from TEMP_CPERF
where C_ID = 12345;
```

And I got result as 0.35. Where as the exact time difference is 0.21. Please help how to get the exact time difference in minutes.

Comment: 21 seconds mean 0.35 minutes, not 0.21 minutes.

Comment: Your code is correct as 0.35 minutes = 21 seconds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed to multiply result by 60 once more (for seconds). Difference of two dates is number of days between them.

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select to_date('16-SEP-23 15:08:35', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') -
  3            to_date('16-SEP-23 15:08:14', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') diff
  4     from dual
  5    )
  6  select diff as days,
  7    diff * 24 as hours,
  8    diff * 24 * 60 as minutes,
  9    diff * 24 * 60 * 60 as seconds
 10  from temp;

      DAYS      HOURS    MINUTES    SECONDS
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
,000243056 ,005833333        ,35         21
```

---

If you switch to timestamps, things get more obvious; difference of two timestamps is *interval day to second*, and then extract anything you want out of it:

```
SQL> with temp as
  2    (select to_timestamp('16-SEP-23 15:08:35', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') -
  3            to_timestamp('16-SEP-23 15:08:14', 'dd-mon-yy hh24:mi:ss') diff
  4     from dual
  5    )
  6  select diff int_day_to_sec,
  7    extract (hour from diff) as hours,
  8    extract (minute from diff) as minutes,
  9    extract (second from diff) as seconds
 10  from temp;

INT_DAY_TO_SEC                      HOURS    MINUTES    SECONDS
------------------------------ ---------- ---------- ----------
+000000000 00:00:21.000000000           0          0         21
```

Comment: The question is "How to find exact time difference in minutes between two date columns?" and the body states "I want to get the time difference in minutes from these two dates." From this it is difficult to see why you think the OP would want a result returned as seconds when they have asked, twice, for it as minutes.